# ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter scrolls before closing

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to let users scroll through videos using a `VideoView`. It works fine, but when you press the back button, the viewpager scrolls to the left and briefly shows the previous `ViewView` before closing the viewpager activity.

I understand the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` will cache the fragments/views for better memory management, but it seems odd to show the precious view before closing. Is this normal, or is there any way to make sure a view is completely hidden when it's not the current pager in focus?

Here's the code for my Adapter. Basically I return one of two fragments that creates a view with that photo or video in it.

```
 inner class MyAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
        override fun getCount(): Int = photoInfo.size
        override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any?): Int = super.getItemPosition(`object`)

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            when (photoInfo[position].type) {
                PHOTO -> {
                    return PhotoFragment.newInstance(photoInfo[position])
                }
                VIDEO-> {
                    return VideoFragment.newInstance(photoInfo[position])
                }
                else -> {
                    return PhotoFragment.newInstance(photoInfo[position])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the videofragment:

```
class VideoFragment : Fragment(), AnkoLogger {
    internal var photo: String? = null
    internal var totalSize: Int? = null
    internal var thumbnail: String? = null
    var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null
    var simpleExoPlayerView: SimpleExoPlayerView? = null
    var error = false
    var shouldLoop = true
    var autoPlay = true
    var proxy: HttpProxyCacheServer? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        photo = arguments.getString("photo")
        thumbnail = arguments.getString("thumbnail")
        totalSize = arguments.getInt("size")
        shouldLoop = defaultSharedPreferences.getBoolean("loop_webm_preference", true)
        autoPlay = defaultSharedPreferences.getBoolean("autplay_webm_preference", true)
        proxy = getProxy(activity)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        player?.release()
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
    }
    fun checkAndSetVolume() {
        val isMuted = defaultSharedPreferences.getBoolean("mute_video", false)
        when (isMuted) {
            true -> {
                simpleExoPlayerView?.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.exo_mute)?.imageResource = R.drawable.volume_on
                player?.volume = 0f
            }
            false -> {
                simpleExoPlayerView?.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.exo_mute)?.imageResource = R.drawable.volume_off
                player?.volume = 1f
            }
        }

    }

    override fun getUserVisibleHint(): Boolean {
        return super.getUserVisibleHint()
    }

    override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if (!isVisibleToUser) {
            player?.playWhenReady = false
            player?.playbackState
            player?.seekTo(0)
        } else if (isVisible && isVisibleToUser && (proxy?.isCached(photo) == true) && !error) {
            checkAndStartAutoplay()
        }
    }

    fun checkAndStartAutoplay() {
        checkAndSetVolume()
        player?.playWhenReady = autoPlay
        player?.playbackState
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        simpleExoPlayerView = SimpleExoPlayerView(context)

        val mainHandler = Handler()
        val bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter()
        val videoTrackSelectionFactory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter)
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory)
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector)

        val fl = FrameLayout(context)

        simpleExoPlayerView?.player = player
        simpleExoPlayerView?.setShutterBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

        player?.repeatMode = if (shouldLoop) 1 else 0

        player?.addListener(object : Player.DefaultEventListener() {
            override fun onPlayerError(error: ExoPlaybackException?) {
                val tv = TextView(context)
                tv.text = getString(android.R.string.VideoView_error_text_unknown)
                tv.textColor = Color.WHITE
                tv.textAlignment = TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
                fl.addView(tv, FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER))
                this@VideoFragment.error = true
            }

            override fun onLoadingChanged(isLoading: Boolean) {
                super.onLoadingChanged(isLoading)
                if (!isLoading) {
                    if (this@VideoFragment.isVisible && this@VideoFragment.userVisibleHint) {
                        checkAndStartAutoplay()
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        val proxyUrl = proxy?.getProxyUrl(photo)

        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "Omnichan"), bandwidthMeter)
        val videoSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(proxyUrl))
        player?.prepare(videoSource)

        fl.addView(simpleExoPlayerView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER))
        simpleExoPlayerView?.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.exo_mute)?.setOnClickListener {
            val isMuted = defaultSharedPreferences.getBoolean("mute_video", false)
            defaultSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("mute_video", !isMuted).apply()
            checkAndSetVolume()
        }

        return fl
    }

    companion object {
        internal fun newInstance(photoInfo: PhotoInfo): VideoFragment {
            val f = VideoFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putString("photo", photoInfo.photoUrl)
            args.putString("thumbnail", photoInfo.thumbnailUrl)
            f.arguments = args
            return f
        }

        private var sharedProxy: HttpProxyCacheServer? = null

        private fun newProxy(context: Context): HttpProxyCacheServer {
            return HttpProxyCacheServer.Builder(context)
                    .maxCacheSize((1024 * 1024 * 256).toLong())       // 256 Mb for cache
                    .build()
        }

        fun getProxy(context: Context): HttpProxyCacheServer {
            return sharedProxy ?: newProxy(context)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add some code... What have you done

Comment: Done. I'm mainly trying to figure out if this behavior is considered normal or not though